# On the sequence $a(n)=\gcd(2^n-1,\phi(2^n-1))$

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, integer-sequences, factorization

For natural $n$, define the sequence

$$
a(n)=\gcd(2^n-1,\phi(2^n-1))
$$

It doesn't appear to be in OEIS and starts
$1,1,1,1,9,1,1,1,3,1,9,1,3,1,1,1,27,1,75,49$

> Q1 Can we unconditionally prove $a(n)=1$ infinitely often?

(Infinitely many Mersenne primes $M_p$ implies it).

> Q2 Can we unconditionally prove $a(n)$ is bounded infinitely often?

> Q3 Can we unconditionally prove $a(n)$ is unbounded infinitely often?

> Q4 In case $a(n)$ is unbounded infinitely often,
> is its factorization related to named prime numbers?

Experimental investigation is not very tractable because
of expensive factorization.

Comment: "unbounded infinitely often" is just "unbounded".

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thanks, you are right.

Answer (score 7):

Q3: certainly yes. Take $n=2\cdot 3^{k}$, then $2^n-1$ is divisible by $3^{k+1}$,thus $3^k$ divides $a(n)$.

As for Q1 and Q2, I do not see how to avoid the scenario when $2^n-1$ is always divisible by a square of a prime.

Comment: Thanks, you have sharp eye about divisibility and recognizing square factors.